# bootstrap modal disappears when mouse off browser window, doesn't return

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a quick CodePen to highlight the issue.

https://codepen.io/robbullock/pen/NwWqYE

1) Hover over the card
2) Click "Request Access" button
3) Mouse off the screen and the modal disappears and doesn't come back.

I believe the issue that's causing the problem is with the ".content .content-overlay" classes below, along with the corresponding hover effects.

```
.content .content-overlay {
background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
position: absolute;
height: 270px;
width: 270px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
border-radius:8px;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.content:hover .content-details {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this type of behavior?

Comment: bootstrap version ?

Comment: Have you added any of your own css to the modal or elements that are in the modal? If you have it would be good to post it here. Also, the same goes for any Javascript.

Comment: Where is the rest of the modal html? Can you add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have left the `.content-overlay` element unclosed and so it wrap the modal element as well. So when you mouse out of the page, the `:hover` rules do not apply and the modal goes away as its container is hidden.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqdedj

Answer (score 1):

move the modal out of the < li > tag

```
<li class="col-md-4 content allAvail">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-title-none">Title</p>
      <p class="card-type">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-overlay">
    <div class="card-content content-details-noaccess fadeIn">
      <div class="about">About</div>
      <div class="description">text and some stuff</div>

      <button type="button" class="button primary-request" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request Access</button>

      <a href="/">
        <button class="button secondary-btn-noaccess">View Details</button>
      </a>
    </div>


    <!-- CC MODAL ACCESS -->

  </div>
</li>
<!-- END MODAL -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```